# Mextram Spice Model for Transistor

Tags: transistors, simulation, spice

Where should I look for a Spice Mextram model for commercial transistors, such as the FMMT415?

or

Should I try a more advanced analog simulation software, incorporating Mextram or similar transistor modelling capabilities?

**Context**

Since several weeks I have been looking for a good Avalanche Transistor Model, able to simulate an Avalanche Oscillator, for a *standard* Spice Simulator.

- [LabCenter Proteus Design Suite](https://www.labcenter.com/),
- [Altium Designer](https://www.altium.com/altium-designer/),
- [Cadence OrCAD PSpice](https://www.orcad.com/products/orcad-pspice-designer/overview),
- [LTSpice](http://www.analog.com/en/design-center/design-tools-and-calculators/ltspice-simulator.html),
- etc.

The purpose of the simulator, rather than the electrical behavior that can be readily tested by breadboarding, is to test some impedance and charge physical models over an unknown net (to be tested on field), hence the need of having a reasonably good (not perfect) knowledge of how the transistor can operate.

I found the [www.diodes.com](https://www.diodes.com/products/discrete/bipolar-transistors/special-function-transistors/avalanche-transistors/part/FMMT415#tab-details) FMMT415 Avalanche Transistor Spice model, which I never was able to reproduce for the specific the avalanche effect, perhaps because:

- The model simply do not implement the avalanche | breakdown, despite of their several switches,
- The effect is different to what I expected (the shown curve vs the simulated one),
- I was probably unable to reproduce it in the simulator, by putting a controlled \$V_{CB}\$ voltage source and a controled \$I_E\$ current source). Because a controlled Current Source do not allow me to put a Voltage source sharing a node simultaneously (remembering the current source carry a non-controlled voltage),
- I should made a sweep in another variable (which one?),
- The simulation do not converge for modelling the avalanche. Which I think is false, because neither the breakdown is observed,
- Another totally different reason.

[image: VCE-IE Curve for the Avalanche Effect]
[image: Transistor Model]
[image: Transistor Curves]

The next advanced model in the scale should be the so called [Mextram](https://www.nxp.com/wcm_documents/models/bipolar-models/mextram/mextramdefinition_504.7.pdf) 503 + 504 model series, which brought to me a totally *new family* of simulators in answer for the Verilog-AMS models for Mextram available in [Auburn.edu](http://www.eng.auburn.edu/~niuguof/mextram/codes/index.html), at least, new for me:

- [Cadence Spectre Circuit Simulator](https://www.cadence.com/content/cadence-www/global/en_US/home/tools/custom-ic-analog-rf-design/circuit-simulation/spectre-circuit-simulator.html),
- [Cadence Virtuoso Analog Design Environment](https://www.cadence.com/content/cadence-www/global/en_US/home/tools/custom-ic-analog-rf-design/circuit-design/virtuoso-analog-design-environment.html),
- [Keysight Advanced Design System](https://www.keysight.com/en/pc-1297113/advanced-design-system-ads?cc=US&lc=eng),
- [Silvaco SmartSpice Simulator](https://www.silvaco.com/products/analog_mixed_signal/smartspice.html),
- [Synopsis HSpice AMS Design](https://www.synopsys.com/verification/ams-verification/circuit-simulation/hspice.html),
- etc.

At this moment I have not been able to model any of these softwares, but, I am in the right way? Should I seriously start trying these software if I care about the avalanche?

For sure, I am clear on my current need about simulating with a reasonable accuracy, just good and average but not perfect or astronomical, allowing me to have some way to predict what is going to happen in the board, and perhaps make some RF analysis or others, if I would like, in the future.

Comment: In what context are you trying to model the avalanche behaviour? Do you need it to relate to a real device or can it be a generic model? Would the [VBIC](http://www.designers-guide.org/VBIC/) model suffice? Have you considered starting with an [avalanching diode first](https://www.onsemi.com/pub/Collateral/AND8254-D.PDF)?

Comment: For the convergence problems did you try to add series resistance and shunt capacitance?

Comment: @loudnoises I only need a reasonable simulation for a transistor i can purchase. I see the VBIC model is also at the same level of the Mextram. I fear i also need to change into an advanced simulator such as Keysight ADS?. I am ok with trying those Avalanche Diodes if that provide me a better insight on how to proceed. I am actually looking for some real transistor (spice) macro model just enough to give me a realistic avalanche | breakdown effect.

Comment: @HKOB Yes i tried. I use them for catching basic problems, but the simulation were unchanged. Hence i do not believe the FMMT415 spice model includes avalanche | breakdown.

Comment: LTspice claims to have MEXTRAM 504: *"The model parameter "level" can be used to specify another type of BJT in LTspice. Set Level=504 to use the MEXTRAM 504 transistor due to NXP(Philips)."* But the documentation is lacking.

Comment: I am curious if this is possible within a standard spice engine. From my (limited) understanding of the algorithms used, I don't think it can use any "state" to remember if the transistor is past avalanche or not, and when it linearizes the device around the operating point it is now, it just chooses one of the two. 

Don't quote me on this though - I am far from a spice guru

Comment: @hyprfrcb Probably easiest, you should just write Mike Engelhardt (I can provide a direct address or you can just write to ltspice@linear.com) and ask for his advice. Second, you should contact researchers who specialize in this area (Mike probably can provide some thoughts, there.) Third, there are texts on the subject. You will then require full 3D details and associated production variations of same, including doping and annealing details that manufacturers will NOT want to provide you as it provides insights into processing details they'd like not to disclose. Best wishes.

Comment: @hyprfrcb Gas discharge physics needs at least 2 spatial and 1 time dim of PDEs tied to >= 6-dim ODEs to apprehend. (Not including radiation transport and atomic interactions.) Simpler uses global rate eqs assuming spatially avg densities for charged and neutral particles, but still needs to deal with excited and metastable states. An intermediate text by Lieberman and Lichtenberg, "Principles of Plasma Discharges and Materials Processing," treats discharge fundamentals using those simplified global rate models, plus collisions & DC & RF discharges. Point? Not simple, so find good researchers.

Comment: @jonk I am clearly not at the level for introducing myself into the dynamics of the process, even for contacting researchers. I think my best choice is use some simulation package as user level at most.

Comment: @HKOB I will check this suggestion for the LTSpice Level=504 option, and also at the ltspice@linear.com contact, for more clues on this confusion.

Comment: @hyprfrcb Then probably follow my recommendation and contact Mike Engelhardt at Linear, unless you know of a better contact for such things. This is an area where he specializes (simulation) and has been doing so, for decades. Probably could listen to what you want to achieve and tell you just where to go (or, alternately, repair your thinking about the problem and help clarify the situation.)

Comment: He replied me!. He is on vacation, so i decided not to disturb him until he is back. I will keep you guys informed...

Comment: @Brethlosze So, what's taken place??? Have you received some help on this question from Mike?

Comment: I didn't receive reply after a second email, but I had to put a freeze on a few months over this application, but for sure I have to retake this during the following months.